# Link a stylesheet with Eclipse / Aptana

Tags: css, eclipse, stylesheet, aptana

L.S.,

I'm using Eclipse with the Aptana Studio-plugin. I wish to create a link to a stylesheet in my html-document. Now I was hoping there would be a feature (similar to Dreamweaver) that could automatically genereate/insert the link tag and attributes. Say I would right-click on the stylesheet in question, and then select an option "link to" and it would insert the tag in my html-file.

Does such an option exist? I'm relatively new to Eclipse/Aptana, and I have not been able to find it so far. (I'd imagine this feature would work for javascripts files as well?)

Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in Aptana Studio yet. You could file a request for this at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD though.

As an alternative way you could do some manual typing in editor with help form code assist.
It will help you on tag/attribue names as well as it will list possible filenames for href attribute.

Cheers,
Max

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio you can grab a stylesheet from the solution explorer and drag it in your html file. This creates the link element automatically. Maybe it's the same in Aptana?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it with a couple of different files and with most of the user perspectives, but it doesn't seem to work that way in Eclipse (or Netbeans). Maybe I should switch to VS?

Comment: Yes I also tested it now, this answer is useless for Aptana. I was too quick to answer this question. The choice for an IDE is very personal. I used both Aptana and VS2010 and personally I think the autocomplete support in VS is slightly better. But I'm also a .NET developer so I'm very used to this IDE. I think it's worth a try. (You will need Visual Web Developer Express)

Comment: If any Aptana, Eclipse developers read this thread, it would definitely be a very useful feature to add. I'm not familiar with the architecture of these programs, but maybe on a drag-and-drop action instead of linking to the files, if the file-to-be-dropped-upon is an HTML file, the program could generate the <link> tag. Same thing for javascript files, images, etc.

Comment: May I suggest you to start a discussion about this over here -> http://www.aptana.com/support.